# Powermockito NotAMockException even though object is a mock

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, powermockito

I am trying to mock Uri.parse() to always return a mocked Uri object. Unfortunately I am told, that the object I try to return is not a mocked object, but I am unable to understand why.

My code:

```
package com.example.recyclerview;

import android.net.Uri;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Uri.class})
public class SimpleExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void setup(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Uri.class);
        Uri uri = mock(Uri.class);
        try {
            // this line causes the error
            PowerMockito.when(Uri.class, "parse", anyString()).thenReturn(uri);
            // also tried line below, but still got the same error:
            // PowerMockito.doReturn(uri).when(Uri.class, "parse", anyString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
// Unit Tests
    //jUnit
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Mockito
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'
    // Mockito mock okHttp Response (and probably other final classes)
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
    // Json for mockito
    testImplementation 'org.json:json:20140107'
    // Instant executor rule
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    // PowerMockito to extend Mockito for static methods
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.5"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.5"
```

This is the error I get:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class java.lang.Class
```

Comment: which version of powermockito are you using? looks like it is executing another method than the one you expect. Did you try passing your uri object instead of the .class in the when method?

Comment: I updated the question to contain my gradle file.
Yes, I tried. In the original code this line works fine:
 ```when(uriMock.toString()).thenReturn(uriString);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seemed to be related to Mockito/Powermockito problems.
To solve this issue I had to use these Mockito versions:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'

testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0"
```

See also the discussion here:
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/992#issuecomment-537439824